# Does a Mixin By Definition Allow Storing Data in Mixin-Level Instance Variables?

Tags: mixins

Several implementations of mixins (e.g. Ruby mixin, Scala trait) include support for storing data (e.g. variables, properties) between method calls in instance variables. There was a bit of debate in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218903/81973) about whether or not a Java virtual extension method qualified as a mixin because they cannot store data in this way; all variables are inputted and outputted within the scope of the method call and cannot be stored in an instance variable. Essentially, there was debate about what a "mixin" by definition is and whether or not implementations in Ruby and whatnot go beyond the commonly recognized definition of the programming concept.

Unfortunately, the definition of a mixin seem rather vague in this regard. For instance, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin#Definition_and_implementation) the following:

> With mixins the class definition defines only the attributes and parameters associated with that class; methods are left to be defined elsewhere, as in Flavors and CLOS, and are organized in "generic functions". These generic functions are functions that are defined in multiple cases (methods) by type dispatch and method combinations.

The above says that a mixin defines attributes, but doesn't cite sources that might clarify this. However, [every](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MixIn) [other](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-mixin.htm) [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mixin) simply fails to mention whether or not mixins allow storing data or if they are limited to methods. To further add confusion, Wikipedia earlier describes mixins as `an interface with implemented methods`, but interfaces can't store instance variables. I tried to find out how it was defined in [Flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavors_%28computer_science%29), which was the first programming language to use something called "mixins", but I couldn't find enough information online about it.

So can a mixin by definition allow storing data? Or is this something that is ambiguous and is left up to the programming language to decide?

Comment: I don't understand the question... Languages decide their features and whether they have mixins or traits or what have you, what those are capable of is defined by the language... I don't see how language features relate to data storage?

Comment: Isn't saving data part of a method's behavior (if desired)?  Seems as if the Wikipedia definition leaves such behavior up to the programmer.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa, I'm asking about the consensus definition of what it is. For instance, what do people mean when they ask "Does X language support mixins?". This was prompted by the Java Virtual Extension Method question I linked to where the two answers didn't seem to agree on what a mixin is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the difference would be whether or not data can be stored in instance variables or whatnot or if it's just for the one method call. You could have a method that inputs and outputs data, then deletes all references to it in memory as soon as the method call ends.

Comment: There is no canonical definition, just the first implementation and then others who did something similar and reused the term. Mostly they called it something else, in fact, and then somebody asked "Is this a mixin?" and they said "I guess so". Surely a precise definition of the *behaviour* is what matters, not some vague label.

Comment: You have misinterpreted the paragraph you quote; it is specifically about the nature of mixins in Simula, following on directly on from the previous paragraph.

Comment: The first sentence seems to be about Simula (which having been made in the 1960s predated any concept of mixins) and then the second paragraph onwards talked about its introduction in Flavors and CLOS. Granted, it is ambiguous though and the Wikipedia article could use some cleanup.

Comment: There's a challenge for you, then.

Comment: @itsbruce if what most people call a mixin is what the first implementation used, then that's good enough for me (in other words, the definition of a mixin is the design pattern used by the first thing that called itself a mixin). As I said in the answer, my Google-fu failed me to find out exactly what it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper *Mixin-based Inheritance* by Bracha and Cook [[PDF]](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/MixinBasedInheritance/MixinBasedInheritance.pdf) shows that inheritance as found in the languages *Smalltalk*, *Beta* and *CLOS* can be reinterpreted as specializations of mixin inheritance.

The main point here is that inheritance can be viewed as a linear application of abstract *deltas* to a base class, e.g.

```
class Foo {
  int num = 42;
  int doStuff() { return num; }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  void otherStuff() { return; }
}
```

– here we could interpret both classes as deltas: The `Foo` mixin adds a `doStuff` method and a `num` member, while `Bar` adds `otherStuff`. However, mixins can't be instantiated on their own (are abstract). Expressed this way, with mixin composition via the `⊕` operator:

```
mixin MFoo {
  int num = 42;
  int doStuff() { return num; }
}

class Foo = MFoo ⊕ Object;

mixin MBar {
  void otherStuff() { return; }
}

class Bar = MBar ⊕ Foo
          = MBar ⊕ (MFoo ⊕ Object)
```

Classical single inheritance is a specialization of mixins where each delta can only be applied to a single superclass (`MBar` can only be applied to `Foo`, but not also to `Baz`).

**If single class inheritance can be viewed as a specialization of mixins, then mixins *allow* the inheritance of data!** However, a specific specialization of mixins need not *require* this. Both class inheritance and interfaces are specializations of mixins.

Java's extension methods do not allow storage of state, thus Java 8 interfaces are not able to model class inheritance. Therefore, these interfaces are not mixins in the sense of Bracha and Cook. They do however offer mixin-like functionality in that they allow to inherit functionality from multiple types, thus providing a weak kind of multiple inheritance.

---

Two points remain worth mentioning, although they are tangential to my argument:

First, nowadays *traits* are all the rage. This is an extension of mixins that doesn't require linear composition. All newer mixin-like systems actually implement traits or at least call them such.

Second, the design rationale for extension methods in Java 8 is not primarily to add mixins, traits, or multiple inheritance but rather to add the ability to retroactively extend existing interfaces to use new methods. It is intended that these extension methods are overridden by implementing classes. Importantly, this allows to update the `Collection` interface to include methods like the higher-order function `map` without breaking code that implemented `Collection` during Java 7 times and thus has no implementation for `map`.

Comment: Thanks for thoroughly explaining this. I especially like how you compared and contrasted it to similar programming concepts to better distinguish it.